# perl wkhtmltopdf Error: Unable to write to destination

Tags: linux, perl, cgi, wkhtmltopdf

I have the following code running as CGI.  It starts to run and returns an empty PDF file to the browser and writes an error message to the error_log.

Does anybody have suggestions on how to solve this?

linux: Linux version 2.6.35.6-48.fc14.i686.PAE (...) (gcc version 4.5.1 20100924 (Red Hat 4.5.1-4) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Fri Oct 22 15:27:53 UTC 2010

wkhtmltopdf: wkhtmltopdf 0.10.0 rc2

perl: This is perl 5, version 12, subversion 2 (v5.12.2) built for i386-linux-thread-multi

Thank You in Advance.
~Donavon

perl CODE:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#### takes string containing HTML and outputs PDF to browser to download
#### (otherwise would output to STDOUT)

print "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='testPDF.pdf'\n";
print "Content-type: application/octet-stream\n\n";

my $htmlToPrint = "<html>a bunch of html</html>";

### open a filehandle and pipe it to wkhtmltopdf
### *the arguments "- -" tell wkhtmltopdf to get
###  input from STDIN and send output to STDOUT*
open(my $makePDF, "|-", "/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf", "-", "-") || die("$!");
print $makePDF $htmlToPrint;  ## sends my HTML to wkhtmltopdf which streams immediately to STDOUT
```

error_log message:

```
Loading pages (1/6)
QPainter::begin(): Returned false============================] 100%
Error: Unable to write to destination
```

Comment: [Crossposted at PerlMonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1085338).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code that I got to work.  Hopefully some folks will find it useful.

Make sure the rights are set up correctly on the server side. We have a sysadmin here that set the module up on the server side so I can't tell you what those need to be, just that it can cause problems.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use IPC::Open3;
use Symbol;

my $cmd = '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf - -';

my $err = gensym(); 
my $in  = gensym();
my $out = gensym();

my $pdf = '';

my $pid = open3($in, $out, $err, $cmd)  or die "could not run cmd : $cmd : $!\n";

my $string = '<html><head></head><body>Hello World!!!</body></html>';

print $in $string;
close($in);

while( <$out> ) {
  $pdf .= $_
}

# for trouble shooting
while( <$err> ) {
  # print "err-> $_<br />\n";
}

# for trouble shooting
waitpid($pid, 0 ) or die "$!\n";
my $retval =  $?;
# print "retval-> $retval<br />\n";

print "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='testPDF.pdf'\n";
print "Content-type: application/octet-stream\n\n";
print $pdf;
```